# What's with the π (Pi) votes?

Tags: support, voting, security, unicoins, april-fools

I know how to count and I know about integers. One of answers on my question has got π (Pi) votes.

[image: Pi votes]

How is it possible? Has security of Stack Exchange been compromised?

Comment: Yes, Stack Exchange has been compromised. If you haven't already, now would be a good time to start panicking.

Comment: Why am I suddenly thinking of Sandra Bullock?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's not PI, it's two T's.  The vote count is base64 encoded (presumably someone forgot to decode it somewhere, or encoded it twice by accicent).  Decoding it tells us that the real vote count is 211.

Comment: Its a bug then?

Comment: No, it's pi - I hacked the HTML on this page for comparison - https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtrmezpbf70mnvq/Screenshot%202014-04-01%2010.52.22.png Good theory, but -1.

Comment: Two T's... how does one pronounce that?

Comment: @AndrewBarber "cry"

Comment: @djechlin "hacked"? Hope they don't catch you ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: It's pronounced just the way it's spelled.

Answer (score 20):

That's not pi, that's a table.
This should indicate a good answer, as the table is still on its feet.

If it was bad, this would happen:
[image: meme table flip]

Answer (score 10):

Stack Exchange has been compromised by thirsty unicorns, as you can see in the widget on the side of the screen.

Please do not panic and try to remain calm. Our experts will be on call to listen to you in only 6 to 8 weeks.

Answer (score 8):

A pi vote is entirely irrational.  In short, there's no justification for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you saw a Pi (π) I have to ask:

1. Do you suffer migraines?
2. Do you have this little neighborhood kid who annoys you asking you for complex calculations (complex for regular stupid people, of course)?

If the answer on both is a Yes, I'll ask you to throw that electric drill you must have hidden somewhere.